# PHP add text using FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf

i see this demo
http://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/demos/simple-demo/

```
<?php
require_once('fpdf.php');
require_once('fpdi.php');

// initiate FPDI
$pdf = new FPDI();
// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();
// set the source file
$pdf->setSourceFile("PdfDocument.pdf");
// import page 1
$tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1);
// use the imported page and place it at point 10,10 with a width of 100 mm
$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 10, 10, 100);

// now write some text above the imported page
$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica');
$pdf->SetTextColor(255, 0, 0);
$pdf->SetXY(30, 30);
$pdf->Write(0, 'This is just a simple text');

$pdf->Output();
```

i want add try  3 text  and different coordinat (X,Y)

i trying

```
$pdf->Write(142.5,170 'This is just a simple text');
$pdf->Write(118,175, 'This is just a simple text');
$pdf->Write(167.5,175, 'This is just a simple text');
```

and  i delete  code

```
$pdf->SetXY(30, 30);
```

not working, i'm confused :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Write(float h, string txt [, mixed link])
>
> This method prints text from the current position. When the right margin is reached
>   (or the \n character is met) a line break occurs and text continues from the left
>   margin. Upon method exit, the current position is left just at the end of the text. 
>   It is possible to put a link on the text.
>
> Parameters
>
> h    - Line height.
>   txt  - String to print.
>   link - URL or identifier returned by AddLink().

As you can see, the first argument is not a position. You have to `SetXY` at first to the location where you want to have your text, `Write` it, `SetXY` for another location and `Write` next string and so on..

```
$pdf->SetXY(x1, y1); // position of text1, numerical, of course, not x1 and y1
$pdf->Write(0, 'Text1');
$pdf->SetXY(x2, y2); // position of text2
$pdf->Write(0, 'Text2');
$pdf->SetXY(x3, y3); // position of text3
$pdf->Write(0, 'Text3');
```

Comment: sir, give me example
i don't understand